# copy eclipse keyboard shortcuts to another eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

How can I copy eclipse shortcuts from one eclipse to another??
I am trying to move from eclipse indigo to eclipse kepler, how can I copy all my custom keyboard shortcuts to my eclipse kepler. . . .??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export your Eclipse settings: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftimpandexp.htm

**From the Eclipse page:**

*To import a preference file:*

1. Select  command link File > Import.
2. In the Import wizard select General > Preferences and click Next.
3. Click Browse... and locate the Preferences file on the file system.
4. Click Import all to accept all of the preferences defined in the
   file.
5. If you want to import only few preferences, choose them from the
   list.
6. Click Finish.

The Export wizard can be used to export preferences from the Workbench to the file system.

To export a preference file:

1. Select  command link File > Export.
2. In the Export wizard select General > Preferences and click Next.
3. Click Export all to add all of the preferences to the file.
4. If you want to export only few preferences, choose them from the
   list.
5. Click Browse... and locate the preferences file on the file system.
6. Click Finish

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to export different preferences:

> http://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/11/24/custom-eclipse-shortcuts-import-export/